# Calculator function using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to perform arithmetic calculation by accepting the input from text boxes, depending the operator respective operation should be performed. I am trying to write separate functions for logic and view.. I am Struck not getting to resolve what's going wrong!!

```
[1]: http://plnkr.co/edit/9cyKKbPC0xYmp1qf1u7G?p=preview
```

Comment: please post the code here

Comment: your calculation function has no formal parameters.

Comment: why downvoting? he created a plknr

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en-US"> 
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Assignment</title>  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="main">
<div class="first"> 
Num1:<input type="text" value="0" id="first" class="box1"><br>
Num2:<input type="text" value="0" id="second" class="box1">
<a class="btn" href="javascript:;">Calcule!</a>
</div>

<div class="second">
Op:<input type="text" value="+" id="oper"  class="box2">
</div>
<div id="result"></div>

<div  class="third">
<span id="demo">Sum:0.00</span>
</div>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

I use jQuery

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    //You can captured value
    //With # you capture the ID element, with . you capture the class element
    //First you need a button for calculate
    $('.btn').on("click",function(){
        var first_number = $('#first').val(); 
        var second_number = $('#second').val(); 
        var result = parseInt(first_number)+parseInt(second_number);
        alert(result);
        //You also can add an HTML element with the result
        $('#result').html("The result is "+result);
        //OR in your result
        $('#demo').html("Sum: "+result);

    });
});
```

Now, you need a logic for each operation.

Comment: The span#demo is the html for the result

Comment: yes, but I try to explain the logic, since he has a text in the span. Now I add the demo element, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can change

```
function calculation() {
```

to

```
function calculation(x, y, z) {
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to determine when to execute the function, will you have any button to trigger the action?

I let you here some javascript code that will work inside any function called by the trigger action:

```
 function calculate() {
    var num1 = document.getElementById("first").value;
    var num2 = document.getElementById("second").value;
    var operation = document.getElementById("oper").value;

    if(operation == "+")
        return parseFloat(num1)+parseFloat(num2);
    if(operation == "-")
        return parseFloat(num1)-parseFloat(num2);
    if(operation == "*")
        return parseFloat(num1)*parseFloat(num2);
    if(operation == "/")
        return parseFloat(num1)/parseFloat(num2);
}
```

You can checkout my example working in here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/uTmSD1XWJwSYxbBqyct7?p=preview